# Blocking files in robots.txt with [possibly] more than one file extension

Tags: robots.txt

Is this correct syntax?

```
    Disallow: /file_name.*
```

If not, is there are way to accomplish this without listing each file twice [multiple times]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, according to http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml

> The "*" wildchar in file names is not supported by (all) the user-agents addressed by this block of code. You should use the wildchar "*" in a block of code exclusively addressed to spiders that support the wildchar (Eg. Googlebot).

So, I just use:

```
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

in each page that I wanted to block from search engines.